# How to refer to a subclass field in a CriteriaQuery with a non entity Superclass

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria, jpa

I'm trying to set up a CriteriaQuery predicate for a class `ListCodes` which is an entity. `ListCodes` also has a superclass called `Auditable` which is a MappedSuperClass.

When I try to do this

```
CriteriaQuery < ListCodes > criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(ListCodes.class);
Root < ListCodes > listCodesRoot = criteriaQuery.from(ListCodes.class);
Predicate predicate = builder.equal(listCodesRoot.get("codeTypeCode"), "STATUSIND");
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
```

I'm getting an exception that the `codeTypeCode` attribute can't be found on `Auditable`. However, when I attempt the alternative solution of using `treat` and making a root for `Auditable`, I'm getting an exception that Auditable is only a MappedSuperClass so I can't make it a root.

What's the proper solution here? How can I use CriteriaQuery on the subclass of a MappedSuperClass?

Edit:
Here's the relevant headers for Auditable and ListCodes

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({AuditListener.class})
@XmlRootElement(namespace=WebServiceConstants.MESSAGES_NAMESPACE)
@XmlType(namespace=WebServiceConstants.MESSAGES_NAMESPACE)
public class Auditable {
```

```
@Entity
@Table (name="TB_LIST_CODE")
public class ListCodes extends Auditable implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Column(name="CODE_TYPE_CODE")      
    private String codeTypeCode;
```

Comment: Maybe adding the relevant parts of `Auditable` and `ListCodes` would help? I mean the class annotations and the annotations on the `codeTypeCode`.

Comment: Yes please show the code of Auditable and ListCodes!

Comment: Went ahead and added those